# Convert a javascript one line in more readable code

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm trying to understand a one-line code in Javascript but it's not very obvious.

The line which works:

```
this._iconNeedsUpdate = !0,this._expandBounds(t), t instanceof L.MarkerCluster ? (e || (this._childClusters.push(t), t.__parent = this), this._childCount += t._childCount) : (e || this._markers.push(t), this._childCount++), this.__parent && this.__parent._addChild(t, !0)
```

I tried to convert with code below but it doesn't work:

```
this._iconNeedsUpdate = !0;
this._expandBounds(t);
if (t instanceof L.MarkerCluster) {
    if (!e) {
        this._childClusters.push(t);
        t.__parent = this;
    } else {
        this._childCount += t._childCount;
    }
} else { 
    if (!e) {
        this._markers.push(t);
        this._childCount++;
    }
}
if (this.__parent) {
    this.__parent._addChild(t, !0);
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

---

After your help, the good code is:

```
this._iconNeedsUpdate = true;
this._expandBounds(t);

if (t instanceof L.MarkerCluster) {
  if (!e) {
    this._childClusters.push(t);
    t.__parent = this;
  }
  this._childCount += t._childCount
} else {
  if (!e) {
    this._markers.push(t);
  }
  this._childCount++;
}
if (this.__parent) {
  this.__parent._addChild(t, true);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've counted 6 different JavaScript concepts in the first three lines of the expanded code. What, precisely, don't you understand about it?

Comment: The [encryption] tag on this question makes me laugh.

Comment: So the minified version works but the expanded one doesn't? Is that the problem? (please clarify the question)

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Yes exact, it is the problem. The oneline work and I tried to convert this line in a more readable code.

Comment: I updated the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary conditional operator has the lowest priority.

Also, in `(A || B), C` B will be evaluated only if A is falsy, but C always will.

So the equivalent code would be:

```
this._iconNeedsUpdate = true;
this._expandBounds(t);

if (t instanceof L.MarkerCluster) {
  if (!e) {
    this._childClusters.push(t);
    t.__parent = this;
  }
  this._childCount += t._childCount
} else {
  if (!e) {
    this._markers.push(t);
  }
  this._childCount++;
}
if (this.__parent) {
  this.__parent._addChild(t, true);
}
```

Comment: I guess you could expand the last line `this.__parent...` to an if too

Comment: Yes we could, although it's much more common than the rest of minification and still readable so I left it untuched.

Comment: Expanded because even though it's more common, newcomers will still find it confuse to use && to control the evaluation flow

Comment: I tried this code, there is no syntax error but the result is not the same than the oneline code.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide a jsfiddle example because it is a maxpbox library.

Comment: It's not quite right.  The `this.__parent._addChild(t,true)` is always executed unconditionally.

Comment: James right! What's after the comma actually comes after the conditional operator, my bad. I've also fixed another line. remy could you try again?

Comment: Yes, it works now! Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: @remy feel free to accept/+1 then :)